# PhoneStateListener onSignalStrengthsChanged Average ASU value within ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I was hoping to get help with my following problem.  Basically, I'm trying to collect every `ASU` result returned from `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` method and place each `ASU` value within an `ArrayList` so that the average ASU value can be calculated.  I have tried many different ways, yet can not get correct result.  It seems ArrayList only stores one ASU value(i.e.current value) and over-writes previous ASU value.  Any help is very much appreciated. My attempted code as follows;

```
private class SignalListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {       

        Double strengthAmplitude = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();

        ArrayList <Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while (arrayList.size() <= 5) { //limit array list collection to 6 elements/ASU values 
            arrayList.add(strengthAmplitude);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
            int item = arrayList.get(i);

        if (arrayList.size() == 0)  
        {  
            System.out.println("Warning!  Average can not be calculated");  
        }   
        else  
        {  
            double total = 0;  
            for (double element : arrayList)  
            {  
                total = total + element;  
            }  
            double average = total / arrayList.size();  
            System.out.println("Average ASU value over sample: " + average);  
        }  

        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points to think about:

- keep your ASU values in ArrayList declared outside onSignalStrengthsChanged() - as mentioned by Gabe, you're creating new ArrayList everytime 'onSignal..' fires, so your arrayList contains one item at time; move arrayList outside of onSignalStrengthsChanged(), this way, you'll be adding ASU readings to your member variable arrayList, and you'll be able to calculate average
- what's the point of:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) 
      int item = arrayList.get(i);
  ```

  ???
- in Android, it's recommended to use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) methods instead of 'System.out'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with scoping.  You're creating a new array list each time this function is entered.  You aren't reusing the old one.  THat means you'll never have more than 1 value.  Also, your loops are weirdly redundant.